# Latest Android System Webview update availability in ARC

Tags: webview, google-chrome-arc

We have an Android app we're trying to get working on Chromebook using ARC Welder.  On Android, we required the June 3rd update to Android System WebView (v51) to fix an error we were seeing.  We now see the same error when running the app in ARC on Chromebook.  I suspect that it can be fixed with a WebView update.  How can I find out what version of Android System WebView is included in ARC and how can I update it to the latest?